# SOAP webservice in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm strugling working on how to pass and retrieve data from web service using SOAP in iOS. I have this url http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx and I will used this for testing. I try SOAPEngine but it needs a licence. Can anyone know a free library or sample code on how to achieve this?

I found this tutorial in [IOS Swift Call Web Service using SOAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606146/ios-swift-call-web-service-using-soap) but the example doesn't have parameter when requesting. I want to have a value like the http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit

The only missing is this part:

```
let is_SoapMessage: String = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:cgs=\"http://www.w3schools.com/\"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><cgs:CelsiusToFahrenheit/><cgs:Celcius>20<cgs:Celcius/></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>"
```

Here's my full code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let is_SoapMessage: String = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:cgs=\"http://www.cgsapi.com/\"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><cgs:CelsiusToFahrenheit/>cgs:Celcius>20<cgs:Celcius/></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>"


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let is_URL: String = "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/CelsiusToFahrenheit"

        let lobj_Request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: is_URL)!)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        //var err: NSError?

        lobj_Request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        lobj_Request.HTTPBody = is_SoapMessage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        lobj_Request.addValue("www.w3schools.com", forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")
        lobj_Request.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        lobj_Request.addValue(String(is_SoapMessage.characters.count), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")

        lobj_Request.addValue("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/CelsiusToFahrenheit", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(lobj_Request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            print("Response: \(response)")
            let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("Body: \(strData)")

            if error != nil
            {
                print("Error: " + error!.description)
            }

        })
        task.resume()

    }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

how to change this when I need to submit a value of 20...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

// Swift3
I fixed the problem using the code below:

```
var is_SoapMessage: String = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:cgs=\"http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/\"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><cgs:CelsiusToFahrenheit><cgs:Celsius>20</cgs:Celsius></cgs:CelsiusToFahrenheit></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>"


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let is_URL: String = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx"

        let lobj_Request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: is_URL)!)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        //let err: NSError?

        lobj_Request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        lobj_Request.HTTPBody = is_SoapMessage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        lobj_Request.addValue("www.w3schools.com", forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")
        lobj_Request.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        lobj_Request.addValue(String(is_SoapMessage.characters.count), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        lobj_Request.addValue("http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(lobj_Request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            print("Response: \(response)")
            let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("Body: \(strData)")

            if error != nil
            {
                print("Error: " + error!.description)
            }

        })
        task.resume()

    }
```

Comment: This worked for me thanks, but you  the tempconvert service has moved to http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit.  Essentially I just needed to update your code to reflect the suggestions when you hit that link. :-)

Answer (score 2):

> SOAP webservice in Swift 5

```py
AF.request("URL here",method:.get)
       .response { response in
          if let data = response.data {
            print(data)
            var xml = xmlparser.parse(data)
            print(xml["e1"]["e2"].element?.text)
          }
       }
```