# Geting NSURLConnection error while calling HTTPS Soap service

Tags: ios, web-services, soap, https, nsurlconnection

I am trying to get data from Soap request but getting my app crashed with this error:

```
2016-02-08 11:12:11.524 Example[567:128898] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)
Response: nil
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I have enabled Security settings in plist and calling other services successfully.

Note: The service is on HTTPS, am i getting this error because of this? is this required any certificate?

i am calling soap service for the first time, please also guide me on how to add email parameter in service: (https://[IP]:9897/JLIPolicyinfo.asmx?op=GetEmail_Poldetail)

here is my code that i get from here: ([IOS Swift Call Web Service using SOAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606146/ios-swift-call-web-service-using-soap))

```
        let is_SoapMessage: String = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:cgs=\"http://www.cgsapi.com/\"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><cgs:GetSystemStatus/></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>"

        let is_URL: String = "https://58.27.241.203:9897/JLIPolicyinfo.asmx"

        let lobj_Request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: is_URL)!)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let err: NSError?

        lobj_Request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        lobj_Request.HTTPBody = is_SoapMessage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        lobj_Request.addValue("58.27.241.203", forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")
        lobj_Request.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        lobj_Request.addValue(String((is_SoapMessage.characters.count)), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        //lobj_Request.addValue("223", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        lobj_Request.addValue("http://tempuri.org/GetEmail_Poldetail", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(lobj_Request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            print("Response: \(response)")
            let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("Body: \(strData)")

            if error != nil
            {
                print("Error: " + error!.description)
            }

        })
        task.resume()
```

Here is my plist addition:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>

    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>https://58.27.241.203:9897/JLIPolicyinfo.asmx</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowInsecureHTTPSLoads</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowInsecureHTTPSLoads</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have a self signed certificate that can be also a problem .

**Solution:-**
It will work if you  renew your server's  ssl certificate to use SHA2 and enabling TLS v1.2.

**Possibly a solution:-**
 You have to add this in your info.plist file, so that it can allow non-secure connection:-

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Or even you can  add like this:-

[image]

**Edit:-**

Add this in your info.plist for specific exception.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>testdomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowInsecureHTTPSLoads</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowInsecureHTTPSLoads</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: Have added in my plist

Comment: How to add that certificate? as company sent me 3 files including 2 txt files and 1 certificate file. txt files having some code like base64 with title Begin request.

Comment: You have not mentioned it in your question that you have added it, so that's the reason I have added possible solution . Updated the answer

Comment: I added certificate file in my xocde project.i was using afnetworking.It detects the certificate and allow connecting with self signed we services. just for your info.

Comment: Update the plist entry, then check!

Comment: when i replaced your edit code in plist now my other services are not working... login services ... that is not a soap request

Comment: <key>testdomain.com</key>--- have u replaced this? if yes, what you have provided?

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan you just double clicked that certificate? as i also have a txt file with it... what should i do with it... secondly android guy did not use that certificate and still able to use service... how come?

Comment: I just asked you a simple question, answer that first :- <key>testdomain.com</key>--  you have to replace this with your domain name.

Comment: no i replaced this <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>

Comment: the domain is https://58.27.241.203:9897/JLIPolicyinfo.asmx?op=GetEmail_Poldetail that you are asking and yes i have replaced it with your test domain ... still having that error