# ios 11 - swift 3 - insecure ssl

Tags: swift, ssl, alamofire, ios10, ios11

i keep sending get requests via alaomfire with those settings:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>domain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowInsecureHTTPSLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowInsecureHTTPSLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

But i still get:

```
An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made
```

Could anybody explain this issue to me?

Thanks and Greetings!

Comment: Where are you trying to connect to? How are you trying to do this? Could you provide some example code? Does it happen on any https site?

Comment: it just happends for one specific site, because they have a self signed certifcate... is there any workaround to ignore it?

Comment: Have you tried setting `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to `true` within `NSAppTransportSecurity`? I don't know if you can ship app like this but it would help see if it is a client or a server issue

Comment: But likely updating your server to use TLS v1.2 which would more than likely solve your issue.

Comment: Also, check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35263782/geting-nsurlconnection-error-while-calling-https-soap-service/35263840#35263840